# Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, linker, mach-o

I have tried to add a testunit target to my project but failed enourmously.
My testunit requires libxml2.dylib (actually libxml2.2.dylib) and of course sentestingunit.framework.
I add the libxml2.dylib to the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS in build settings
$(inherited) "$(SYSTEM_APPS_DIR)/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks"

Then I add the sentestingunit.framework in the build phase -> link binary with libraries.
I have my app (called vindfyrar) as a target dependencies.
Now the the build of my testing target start to scream all the stuff below;
Any one got an idea what I have done wrong?
i386? Why?

Beleive me on this one, I have done my homework, i e googled and try every option in the build settings that could possible be wrong... No success.
XCode 4.6 on Lion 10.7.5

Kind regards,
Jan Gifvars

> Ld /Users/jan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vivasjofart-dvimgeakkxnlwqceslyrhdyifmtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DavisTest.octest/DavisTest normal i386
>       cd /Users/jan/utveckling/vivasjofart/vivasjofart
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.1
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -L/Users/jan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vivasjofart-dvimgeakkxnlwqceslyrhdyifmtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/jan/utveckling/vivasjofart/vivasjofart -L/Users/jan/utveckling/vivasjofart/vivasjofart/../../coreplot-examples/DatePlot -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols/usr/lib -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib -F/Users/jan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vivasjofart-dvimgeakkxnlwqceslyrhdyifmtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/jan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vivasjofart-dvimgeakkxnlwqceslyrhdyifmtf/Build/Intermediates/vivasjofart.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DavisTest.build/Objects-normal/i386/DavisTest.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/jan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vivasjofart-dvimgeakkxnlwqceslyrhdyifmtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/vindfyrar.app/vindfyrar -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework SenTestingKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -o /Users/jan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/vivasjofart-dvimgeakkxnlwqceslyrhdyifmtf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DavisTest.octest/DavisTest
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o, missing required architecture i386 in file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o (2 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.dylib (2 slices)
>   ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib, missing required architecture i386 in file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols/usr/lib/libSystem.dylib (2 slices)
>   ld: in '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib', missing required architecture i386 in file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (2 slices) for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

You're linking against the iPhoneOS SDKs (where all the binaries are built for architecture arm) but you're building an iPhone Simulator program (i386).  Your project is linking against the wrong SDK.

Comment: Ok, thanks Jason. <br/>My build settings are <br/>ARCHS == Standard   (armv7, armv7s) and <br/>SDKROOT == iOS 6.1 <br/>SUPPORTED PLATFORMS == iOS and <br/>VALID_ARCHS == armv7. <br/>Are there any other settings that make my target a i386-target?<br/> When I add the SenTestingKit Framework FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATH is set to what you se above. If I delete that entry. Compilation will succed except from the SenTesting references of course. <br/>Please, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I missed these settings HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS
$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2/** CorePlotHeaders/**

LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH
$(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)"
"$(SRCROOT)/../../coreplot-examples/DatePlot"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.2/Symbols/usr/lib
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib

FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS
$(inherited) "$(SYSTEM_APPS_DIR)/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks"

Comment: Please, wait, I think I about to solve this... will let you know.

Comment: Nope, I don't get this. I have followed this link. http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/how-to-add-unit-tests-to-existing-ios-project/ Where do I state that I want a i386 architecture, please this so annoying

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by adding these setting and values.

For Test Host it's $(BUNDLE_LOADER)
For Bundle Loader it's $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/ApplicationName.app/ApplicationProductName

If you want more details log in to apple.developer and search for
"Test case give Apple Mach-O Linker Error"

Thanks everyone for your time!

Kind regards,
Jan Gifvars